# Cleaning non Boolean values in dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with columns that are all boolean values (1 or 0), but there are some columns that have invalid values within that such as; 111, 10, 11.  I need to clean out the data by removing the row of data that has that invalid value within it.  But prior to cleaning out the non boolean values, the first column is Age and I need to clean out the rows by a placing them in a range of 18-150 because there are values such as 700 or 600.

```
cleandata4bestdeal2=cleandata4bestdeal.dropna(axis=0,how=any,inplace = False)
```

I already deleted the rows with values of `NaN` but I am using the above to try and remove all non boolean values.
[CleanDataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46kz4.png)

Comment: Can you give us some sample data?

Comment: Also, why are you using `pandas.DataFrame.dropna()` when those boolean values are clearly not `nan`?

Comment: I added a screen shot of the data above.  And I have used the dropna() and that got rid of the NaN values but it did not get rid of the non boolean values.

Answer (score 0):

```
# create some sample data, since none was provided
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Age': [15, 700, 600, 150, 125, 32, 45, 43, 56, 1002], 'Boolean': ['001', '100', '0', '1', '1', '010', '110', '1', '0', '0']})
>>> print(df)
    Age Boolean
0    15     001
1   700     100
2   600       0
3   150       1
4   125       1
5    32     010
6    45     110
7    43       1
8    56       0
9  1002       0

# keep only those rows for which the 'Age' column is in the inclusive range [18, 150]
>>> new_df = df[df['Age'].isin(range(18, 151))]
>>> print(new_df)
   Age Boolean
3  150       1
4  125       1
5   32     010
6   45     110
7   43       1
8   56       0

# finally, keep only those boolean values that are of length 1 
# (i.e. exclude rows with 'Boolean' values like '110' or '010')
>>> new_df = new_df[new_df['Boolean'].map(len) == 1]
>>> print(new_df)
   Age Boolean
3  150       1
4  125       1
7   43       1
8   56       0
```

Comment: I tried the len thing as well.  How would I do that for multiple columns?  Thank you so much for this piece!  Would I just add a comma within the ['Boolean','New Columns']?

Comment: Ok that does not work, do I have to put that requirement in for each column?  Create like 10 new dataframes?

Comment: I need to do remove the non boolean values from multiple columns.  Like what you had in the above example but say there was another column named Boolean2 with bad data along with 1 and 0 that I need to clean.  I would like to do so in the one line of code if possible.  Just a bit confused so far on how I can do so.

Comment: If you need to apply the same rule (same function) over a certain list of items (e.g. a list of columns), you can try using a `for` loop.